# symlink outside root directory

Tags: php, drupal, apache2, symlink

Ok, I am trying to create a symbolic link using php symlink() function, but am not fully understanding it.  Here is what the issue is.

I have several folders on a network share that has been mounted in the following location:

```
/home/metaimage
/home/opmadbexports
```

Now, I need to symlink these inside of a drupal installation located at the following location:

```
/home/opmadbdev/html/
```

I'm unsure of how to do this.  FollowSymLinks is on.  I just need to code to create a symbolic link and then kill the symbolic link.

EDIT EDIT EDIT

```
/home/metaimage AND /home/opmadbexports
```

are both outside the DOCUMENT_ROOT.  Not sure if that would be causing me the issues I'm having.  Perhaps an alias is a better idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is the code to symlink() the above folders inside of a php script.  And then unlink it.  See the last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it all figured out.  While roychri was on the right track, what I ended up doing was mounting the folders inside the web root, but using .htaccess to disable php.  I needed to avoid backing up all the files once they were mounted, seeing as there are a ton of files.

Once that was done, I was able to use the scripts I had previously written in order to complete the process.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do it:

```
// Syntax is :  symlink ('Where the link point to',  'Name of the link to create');
symlink('/home/metaimage',         '/home/opmadbdev/html/metaimage');
symlink('/home/opmadbexports',     '/home/opmadbdev/html/opmadbexports');

// do stuff

unlink('/home/opmadbdev/html/metaimage');
unlink('/home/opmadbdev/html/opmadbexports');
```

Comment: This is not working.  I am unsure if the root directory is not available to this user.

Comment: No, I don't get any errors.  I set up an if statement to let me know if the symbolic link was successful, and it wasn't.  It gives me a giant F-you (cause I told it to), and won't continue.  Maybe I should mention that /home/metaimage is outside of the Document Root?

Comment: LOL! :)
How do you test if the link was successful precisly?
If you have FollowSymLink then it should not matter where the link point to.

Comment: What I'm doing is the following: if (!symlink('/home/metaimage', '/home/opmadbdev/html/metaimage')) {
 print 'something';
 exit;
}

Comment: And even leaving it in there, but then commenting out the unlink, when I go in under command line, it is not symlinked.

Comment: Maybe the user who runs this symlink (apache or nobody or httpd) does not have permissions to write in /home/opmadbdev/html folder.  You can find who is running the php script with this: `getmypid()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8835/discussion-between-roychri-and-webdevsoup)